# How can I design a hierarchy of agents each of which with different goals?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ai-design, multi-agent-systems, hierarchical-rl

I read some light material earlier about the possibility of building a hierarchy of agents, where the agents at the leaves solve primitive tasks while higher-level agents are optimized for orchestrating direct-descendant agents.

According to my understanding, each agent would have different objective functions and possible moves.

How can I design such a hierarchy of agents each of which with different goals? Are there any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of reinforcement learning, the idea of modeling your goal-oriented problem as a hierarchy of multiple sub-problems is called **hierarchical reinforcement learning**, which gives rise to concepts such as *semi-Markov decision processes* and *options* (aka macro actions). The article [The Promise of Hierarchical Reinforcement Learning](https://thegradient.pub/the-promise-of-hierarchical-reinforcement-learning/) presents and describes the topic quite well, so I suggest you read it.

However, this idea of solving multiple sub-tasks in order to solve a bigger task isn't limited to RL. For example, in the paper [Neural Programmer-Interpreters](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06279.pdf) (NPIs), without referring to the traditional RL topics, a model is proposed to write programs by composing simpler ones.

Another example is genetic programming with *automatically defined functions* (ADFs), where sub-programs (the ADFs) can be re-used in different parts of the program if that's beneficial according to the fitness.

So, there are different ways you can design a system to solve a big task by solving multiple sub-tasks and then compose them. The approach that you choose depends on your use case. If you want to build programs, then NPIs can be a start. If you want to incorporate a time component in your system, then HRL is probably a viable approach. There are several HRL algorithms. Some of them (e.g. [MAXQ-OP](https://github.com/wrighteagle2d/wrighteaglebase)) have been successfully used to solve the [RoboCup challenge](https://www.robocup.org/).